# Facebook login on iOS apps

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook

I`m using Facebook to create a easy login to my application.

Until yesterday it was working fine, if i have the Facebook app open it, if not and i have multitask open safari, if not open a webview.

But today, i was adding push notifications to my app. At the moment the only this i changed was the `appID` and the `AppDelegate` adding

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound )];
```

in the build settings i selected my provision profile for this appID for debug and release.

And now i don't know why but the login button is opening at the same time Facebook app, Safari and the webview. 3 different ways opening at the same time.

there is nothing at http://developers.facebook.com that correlates with this error. does anyone know anything about it?

***EDIT***

I just have tested on other devices, apparently it only happens on my iPhone 4S with iOS 6.beta3

I`ll close this question, sorry

Comment: Have you tried this on a device and the simulator? I really can't imagine why notifications would change this. Also did you try commenting out the `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:`?

Comment: i`m trying only on device, on simulator the Facebook sdk always open safari so no point in testing it there

Comment: What happens if you comment out the notification register in app delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a problem on my app, it is because i`m using iOS 6 beta 3

don't know how to fix it but i`ll try Facebook help

Comment: You said it worked before the notification and changing the app id though right?

Comment: no, i can still make login, but my application receives two cancels or two logins or one login and one cancel, because fb app AND web view on my app both open an make callbacks

Comment: Sorry what I meant is, this bug didn't appear until after the upgrade to the iOS6 beta 3 right?

Comment: Yes, with iOS6 beta 2 i didn't notice this error, only when i upgrade it to iOS6 beta 3

Comment: I would go on the apple forums and discuss this problem. I'm not sure if it's against NDA to post here about it